# GradientLayer shifted to the top left in iOS Swift App

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cagradientlayer

I added a GradientLayer as the Background for my views with the following code:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class MainView: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        sharedInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        sharedInit()
    }
    
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        sharedInit()
    }
    
    func sharedInit() {      
        let colorTop = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
        let colorBottom = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = self.frame
        gradientLayer.colors = [colorTop, colorBottom]
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
}
```

In the Xcode Storyboard preview everything looks as wanted, but in the simulator the background is shifted to the top left corner as seen in following screenshot.

[image: shifted background gradient]

It would be nice if anyone could give me a clue what is happening here.

Thanks.

Comment: Same issue as always with CALayer and wrong size. When `sharedInit` is called, you haven't the real size. The auto layout hasn't been applied yet. Also, `gradientLayer.frame = self.frame` you should always use `self.bounds`: `gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds`.

Comment: Thanks, the hint with not knowing the size helped. I moved the code in the layoutSubview function and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should go to the "layoutSubviews" method in your "MainView" class:-**

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
       super.layoutSubviews()
       sharedInit()
}
```

**Also, replace the line "gradientLayer.frame = self.frame" of "sharedInit" method with following code:-**

```
gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
```

*As I have checked, it's work for me!*

Comment: You should only resize the gradient layer in layoutSubviews, not call the init method, otherwise you will be creating and adding a new gradient layer each time